# How to Stop Click Count in Java Android?

Tags: java, android

I have a problem related click count. The problem is, I can't stop click when a number a click is given.

For example, I allow users to click a button 3 times, if clicks reached 3 times, then stop count, and do what I want.

This is my code I have used.

```
private int clickcount = 3;
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Do button click handling here
        if ( posisi2==getAdapterPosition() ) {
                clickcount--;
                tombolbaca.setText("Baca " + clickcount + "x");

                // try to stop count but it can't, computer still counting
                if (clickcount == 3)
                {
                    mTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    rl2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

        } // adapter

    } // onClick
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this Change,

```
private int clickcount = 3;
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    // Do button click handling here
    if ( posisi2==getAdapterPosition() ) {
            clickcount--;
            tombolbaca.setText("Baca " + clickcount + "x");

            // try to stop count but it can't
            if (clickcount <=0)  <== make this change
            {
                mTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                rl2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

    } // adapter

}
```

Comment: Many thanks for you. Your code is work. But I have no idea, how it work? My logic can't catch it! Can you explain to me?

Comment: @ShubhamVala But you still haven't explained **how** this solution works, other than just "use this code"

Answer (score 4):

I think the trigger to do something might be when the click count is zero, not three:

```
if (clickcount == 0) {
    mTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    rl2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

It isn't clear whether the above `if` statement belongs nested inside the outer `if`, or if it should be at the method level of `onClick()`.

Note: We could have written `if (clickCount <= 0)`, but there may not be a need to do this (nor may it be desirable), since after you have changed the visibility of those elements to `GONE` once, you don't need to do it again.

Comment: Ok,, thanks for your answer.I've changed to zero, and its work. But I have no idea, how it work? My logic can't catch it! Can you explain to me?

Comment: @Sa'adAbdurrazzaq If Tim's answer has helped then please accept it by clicking the ✔ icon underneath the score on the left.

Comment: @MichaelDodd Comment upvoted, because it used a check emoticon.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 private int clickcount = 3;
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Do button click handling here
            if ( posisi2==getAdapterPosition() ) {
                    clickcount--;
                    tombolbaca.setText("Baca " + clickcount + "x");

                    // try to stop count but it can't, computer still counting
                    if (clickcount == 0)
                    {
                        mTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        rl2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

            } // adapter

        } // onClick
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private int clickcount = 0;
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Do button click handling here
        if ( clickcount<3 ) {
                clickcount++;
                tombolbaca.setText("Baca " + clickcount + "x");
}

                //Count stops here..
               else
                {
                    mTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    rl2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

        } 

    }
```